# Logging to a file in android using java.util.logging

Tags: android, logging, java.util.logging

I want to add a logging mechanism in my android in which i want to log messages to a file on the sd card.

Since I had to log from different threads and as I do not want these threads to be blocked, I tried to do logging on a different thread.

I've built a class something like this so far -

```
public class TestLogger {

    private static String LOG_FILE_NAME = "/logs.txt";
    private static int LOG_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT = 100 * 1024;

    private static FileHandler logHandler;  
    private static Logger logger;
    private static ExecutorService executorService;

    public synchronized static void init() {
        String logFilePathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + LOG_FILE_NAME;

        try {
            logHandler = new FileHandler(logFilePathName, LOG_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT, 1, true);
            logHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            logger = Logger.getLogger("com.test.android");
            logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            logger.addHandler(logHandler);
            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private synchronized static void writeLog(String msg) {
        if(logger == null) 
            return;
        logger.log(Level.FINE, msg);
    }

    public static void logMessage(String msg) {
        executorService.submit(new LogToFile(msg));
    }

    private static class LogToFile implements Runnable {

        String msg;

        public LogToFile(String msg) {
            this.msg = msg;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TestLogger.writeLog(msg);
        }
    }

}
```

When the app is entered, I call `TestLogger.init()` and from there on I call `TestLogger.logMessage("log message"); whenever I have to log something to the file.

This works fine but instead of creating `logs.txt`, i also see other files created. Like logs.txt.1 and logs.txt.2 along with their .lck files. By having keyword `synchronized`, have I not made sure that no two threads write to the same file at the same time?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am now using a blocking queue to do the job. it works great now :)

Comment: Hi, I want to implement want the same thing.. can you please post your working code?

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` works with variables not files. You can use the `synchronized` block to fill a string builder for e.g. and write to the file in a final step.